# Child component componentDidMount fires only once

Tags: reactjs

I have an Home.js which renders 2 components, Header and Form Component.
Form component has a button and dialog box. Clicking the button opens up the dialog.

Now as child ComponentDidMount is called before Parents, when Home is rendered, Form ComponentDidMount is fired.

Now when I click on the button in Form component, its ComponentDidMount is not getting fired.

Comment: can you please add your code to the question?

Answer (score 1):

componentDidMount is only called once in the lifecycle of any component, re-render will not reinitialize the component. componentDidUpdate will be called where you can manage your logic.

To make ComponentDIdMount re-render you need to change the props or state passed from home component.